# Draw histograms per row over multiple columns in R

Tags: r, drawing, histogram, ranking

I'm using R for the analysis of my master thesis
I have the following data frame: STOF: Student to staff ratio

```
    HEI.ID   X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012 
1        OP  41.8 147.6  90.3  82.9 106.8  63.0    
2        MO  20.0  20.8  21.1  20.9  12.6  20.6    
3        SD  21.2  32.3  25.7  23.9  25.0  40.1    
4        UN  51.8  39.8  19.9  20.9  21.6  22.5    
5        WS  18.0  19.9  15.3  13.6  15.7  15.2    
6        BF  11.5  36.9  20.0  23.2  18.2  23.8    
7        ME  34.2  30.3  28.4  30.1  31.5  25.6    
8        IM   7.7  18.1  20.5  14.6  17.2  17.1    
9        OM  11.4  11.2  12.2  11.1  13.4  19.2    
10       DC  14.3  28.7  20.1  17.0  22.3  16.2    
11       OC  28.6  44.0  24.9  27.9  34.0  30.7
```

Then I rank colleges using this commend

```
HEIrank1<-(STOF[,-c(1)])
rank1 <- apply(HEIrank1,2,rank)

> HEIrank11
     HEI.ID X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012
1        OP  18.0    20  20.0  20.0  20.0    20
2        MO  14.0     9  13.0  13.5   2.0    12
3        SD  15.0    16  17.0  16.0  16.0    19
4        UN  20.0    18   8.0  13.5  14.0    13
5        WS  12.0     8   4.0   7.0   6.0     8
6        BF   6.5    17   9.5  15.0  10.0    14
7        ME  17.0    15  19.0  19.0  17.0    15
8        IM   2.0     6  12.0   8.0   8.5    10
9        OM   4.5     3   2.5   3.0   3.0    11
10       DC  11.0    14  11.0   9.0  15.0     9
11       OC  16.0    19  16.0  18.0  19.0    17
```

I would like to draw histogram for each HEIs (for each row)?

Comment: I try commend OP<-rank1[1,]
hist(OP,breaks=3) I want to draw histogram as loop

Comment: Each row only has 6 values. Are you sure it even makes sense to draw a histogram from 6 values? Perhaps you means that you want a histogram for each numeric column?

Comment: I want for example (OP) college get rank number (20) 5 times.SO X should be ranks and Y should be frequency. I need help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ggplot you won't need to do it as a loop, you can plot them all at once. Also, you need to reformat your data so that it's in long format not short format. You can use the melt function from the reshape package to do so.

```
library(reshape2)
new.df<-melt(HEIrank11,id.vars="HEI.ID")
names(new.df)=c("HEI.ID","Year","Rank")
```

substring is just getting rid of the X in each year

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(new.df, aes(x=HEI.ID,y=Rank,fill=substring(Year,2)))+
   geom_histogram(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi crmhaske....I try to run the last commends but shows an error..I do not why and i am not good in R.The error is ...(Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot, warn_missing = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "revalue")  so can you help what mistake I did??thank you

Comment: The function revalue is in the plyr package. It's probably a dependency you don't have. Do `install.packages("plyr")` and then `library(plyr)`. It should work after that.

Comment: Hi crmhaske  I try to plot histogram for each college as my adviser need it using                                                     par( mfrow = c( 2, 2 ) )
hist(as.numeric(HEIrank11[1,-1]),nclass=12)                         I want name of college appear in graph.can you help me

Comment: Your histogram code doesn't make sense. You can't have a negative index. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to plot and how it's different from what I and Matthew showed you using ggplot2 and lattice?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in `lattice`:

```
require(lattice)
barchart(X2007+X2008+X2009+X2010+X2011+X2012 ~ HEI.ID,
         data=HEIrank11,
         auto.key=list(space='right')
         )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Matthew....I try to run the commend but shows an error..I do not why and I am not good in R.The error is ...(Error: could not find function "barchart").Can you help me.