# Barplots from data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm a very beginner in R and not familiar with the syntax. Your help would be very much appreciated.

I have a Data frame with 3 columns and 27 rows.

```
Gene_Name Cell_line1 Cell_line2
gene1        23          45
gene2        0.6         21
gene3        34          18
---
gene27       45          23
```

I want to make Grouped Barplot where I have gene names on the X axis and cell_line1 and Cell_line2 values on the Y in different colors.

I was trying to make it with ggplot2

```
 p<- ggplot(data=df, aes(Gene_Names, Cell_line1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Can you correct my code? or suggest something else?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reshape your data to long format, I'd recommend using `reshape2::melt()`

Comment: Also please see [Creating a Great Reproducible Example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4421870)

Comment: This is a very common question on Stack Overflow. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/26345427/7347699

Answer (score 0):

Here's example data, since you didn't provide much to work with:

```
df <- data.frame(Gene_Names = LETTERS, 
                 Cell_line1 = 10, 
                 Cell_line2 = 8)
```

Here's how you reshape the data:

```
df <- df %>% tidyr::gather("Cell_line", "Value", 2:3)
```

Example of a plot as you described:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Gene_Names, y = Value, fill = Cell_line)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = .5)+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```