# How to apply histogram on dependent data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to visualise the proportional data (Nij/n) about the sinus (independent) and arr/AHB (dependent variable) cases in females and males by R. 
`ggplot2` approach and any other is welcome! 
Pseudocode

- histogram of the second and third columns for the groups N11.1, ..., N32.1

Code

```
        N11.1 N22.1 N33.1 N44.1 N21.1 N31.1 N32.1
Sinus     1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  12.0
Arr/AHB   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0  20.9
        N11.1 N22.1 N33.1 N44.1 N21.1 N31.1 N32.1
Sinus     1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   4.0
Arr/AHB   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  24.0
```

The first column has the row.names. Code with the data

```
library("ggplot2")

data.female <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), N32.1 = structure(c(5L, 
7L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", 
"22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", 
"N22.1", "N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")

data.male <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), 
    N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), 
    N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), 
    N32.1 = structure(c(11L, 9L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", 
    "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", "22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", 
    "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", "N22.1", 
"N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")
```

Attempt for a single data row

```
data.female.sinus <- data.female[1:1,1:7]
print(data.female.sinus)

g <- ggplot(data.female.sinus)
g + geom_bar()
#Warning messages:
#1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
#  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
#  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#4: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
#5: Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
#arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1 
#null device
```

Expected output: histogram in comparison between male and female, with emphasis that Arr/AHB is the dependent variable

### Testing hhh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680020/54964)

I do not understand why you cannot use the given data with column names like without column names

```
Sinus <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,12)
ArrAHB <- c(1,0,0,0.1,0,0,20.9)
# Things work with this data  

Sinus <- data.female[1, 1:7]
ArrAHB <- data.female[2, 1:7]
# Things do not work with this data which has column names

Labels <- c("N11.1","N22.2","N33.1","N44.1","N21.1","N31.1","N32.1")
ID <- c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")
data.female <- data.frame(Sinus,ArrAHB,row.names=Labels)
data.female <- t(data.female)

barchart(data.female,auto.key=list(space='right'))
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Question isn't really clear. You are looking for a `ggplot2` solution?

Comment: @drmariod Yes or any other is also ok. Something benchmark would be great.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Your current data.* is all factors. This may be my issue at being dense, but could you create a sample plot (can be written by hand) of what the result is suppose to look like?

Comment: @roman Etc sinus values in y-axis and column names in x-axis.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a [`geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data looks like this:

```
> data.female
        N11.1 N22.1 N33.1 N44.1 N21.1 N31.1 N32.1
Sinus     1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  12.0
Arr/AHB   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0  20.9
> data.male
        N11.1 N22.1 N33.1 N44.1 N21.1 N31.1 N32.1
Sinus     1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   4.0
Arr/AHB   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  24.0
```

and you want to draw histograms of each row over multiple columns (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264744/draw-histograms-per-row-over-multiple-columns-in-r)) so the below demostrating.

**1. Histogram for each row where Sinus and ArrAHB groups separated**

> You want to make a common identifier for Sinus and Arr/AHB so we create a new ID column for that. We use this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22265066/164148) with lattice pkg.
>
> ```
> require(lattice)
> Sinus<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,12)
> ArrAHB<-c(1,0,0,0.1,0,0,20.9)
> Labels<-c("N11.1","N22.1","N33.1","N44.1","N21.1","N31.1","N32.1")
> ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")
> data.female<-data.frame(Sinus,ArrAHB,row.names=Labels)
> data.female<-as.data.frame(t(data.female))
> data.female$ID<-ID
>
> barchart(N11.1+N22.1+N33.1+N44.1+N21.1+N31.1+N32.1 ~ ID,
>          data=data.female,
>          auto.key=list(space='right')
>          )
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> and in comparison this is the chart for Man:
>
> [image]

**1.2. Your Factor data must be converted to vectors or better: read your original files directly into vectors, not factors!**

Your input data is malformated as factor data, bad here, that is probably result of misusing read.csv such as missing hte flag `na.strings="."` or some malformated elements. More:

> *["**Sometimes when a data frame is read directly from a file, a column you’d thought would produce a numeric vector instead produces a factor.** This is caused by a non-numeric value in the column, often a missing value encoded in a special way like . or -. To remedy the situation, coerce the vector from a factor to a character vector, and then from a character to a double vector. (Be sure to check for missing values after this process.) Of course, **a much better plan is to discover what caused the problem in the first place and fix that; using the na.strings argument to read.csv() is often a good place to start.**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#factors)**

In order to use this malformated data, the factor elements must be turnt into numeric values. The class commands reveal your mistake in reading your original data into R such that

```
> class(data.female$N22.1)
[1] "factor"
> as.double(as.character(data.female$N22.1))
[1] 0 0
```

where the `as.double(as.character(...))` allows use to maniputlate the data object again correctly. So the code

```
require(lattice)
data.female <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"),
                              N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"),
                              N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"),
                              N44.1 = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"),
                              N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"),
                              N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"),
                              N32.1 = structure(c(5L, 7L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", "22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", "44.0", "N32"),
                                                class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", "N22.1", "N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"),
                         row.names = c("Sinus", "Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")
data.female$ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")
data.female<-as.data.frame(data.female)

f<-function(x) as.double(as.character(x))   #factors converted to vectors

barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.female,
         auto.key=list(space='right')
         )
```

where the function `f` does the conversion from factors to vectors, alas factors are special kinds of vectors with class object and attribute value, more [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#attributes).

[image]

where you need to manipulate the legend yourself.

**2. Barchart again showing proportions**

> The data input changed to readable format (not output of some CSZ file): values in N32.1 is far larger than any other data in other columns.
>
> ```
> require(lattice)
> Sinus<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,12)
> ArrAHB<-c(1,0,0,0.1,0,0,20.9)
> Labels<-c("N11.1","N22.2","N33.1","N44.1","N21.1","N31.1","N32.1")
> ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")
> data.female<-data.frame(Sinus,ArrAHB,row.names=Labels)
> data.female<-t(data.female)
>
> barchart(data.female,auto.key=list(space='right'))
>
> > data.female
>        N11.1 N22.2 N33.1 N44.1 N21.1 N31.1 N32.1
> Sinus      1     0     0   0.0     0     0  12.0
> ArrAHB     1     0     0   0.1     0     0  20.9
> ```

[image]

Comment: @Masi the input you are giving is something I am not expert in understanding, like 3L standing for double numeric, but for this problem, this is totally uncecessary. Some CSV file output? Anyway, I reformatted the input in Method 2 to show proportions.

Comment: @Masi you can try as.data.frame(ur input data). The new question is to reformat the structure data object to proper data frame. Ask new succint question on formatting if stuck. Lattice and barchart  used here wants certain formatting. I will look at this later

Comment: @Masi Done, see 1.2. Your input is badly formatted, probably some mistake in the original data file or misusing command like read.csv so getting the number values to factors. You should have your data frame in vectors, not factors -- more about the conversion [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) or in my answer point 1.2.

Comment: I think you could take `ID` from `rownames` somehow. I think this can be extraneous `ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")`.