# How to add column to a table in R

Tags: r

I have applied cross tabulation with table() to two columns of my dataframe and I get something like this
[image: cross tabulation]

Now I would like to add here a new column with the row totals but when I try this...

```
tablaCruzada$Total<-0
```

Warning message:
In tablaCruzada$Total <- 0 : Realizando coercion de LHD a una lista

Any idea, please?

regards

Comment: convert matrix to table  with `as.data.frame(tablaCruzada)` or `dplyr::as_tibble(tablaCruzada)`  and then use the `tablaCruzada$Total <- 0 `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: \`ID : Coercing LHS to a list\` in adding an ID column, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681628/r-id-coercing-lhs-to-a-list-in-adding-an-id-column-why)

Comment: If I convert my table object to a dataframe object I lose my columns. I get only 3 columns. var1 with the names, var2 with the Project Codes and freq with the sum by Project and I would like to see all my table columns plus one ore with the sum by each row

Comment: would you mind sharing sample data using `dput(head(tablaCruzada))`?

Comment: Here is the file result of dput; https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zqhjdpum7r1dji/tablacruzada.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `table` to dataframe/matrix first , then add new column using `rowSums`.

Using reproducible example from `mtcars`.

```
temp <- table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am)
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(temp)
df$Total <- rowSums(df)
#Or if you just want to initialize
#df$Total <- 0
df

#   0 1 Total
#4  3 8    11
#6  4 3     7
#8 12 2    14
```

Comment: Thanks the key was as.data.frame.matrix(). I needed matrix to not lose my columns

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore `janitor` package. Here's an example using `iris` dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

iris %>% 
  tabyl(Sepal.Length, Species) %>% 
  adorn_totals(where = "col")

# Sepal.Length setosa versicolor virginica Total
# 4.3      1          0         0     1
# 4.4      3          0         0     3
# 4.5      1          0         0     1
# 4.6      4          0         0     4
# 4.7      2          0         0     2
# 4.8      5          0         0     5
# ....
```

- `tabyl()` provides a 2-way frequency table, where the result is a data.frame
- `adorn_totals()` includes a column for the total

Comment: tabyl(df$JefeProyecto,df$Proyecto)
Error in show_na && sum(is.na(result[[1]])) > 0 : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y' df$JefeProyecto is character and df$Proyecto numeric

Answer (score 0):

Also, based on @Ronak's data, use `apply`

```
df$Total <- apply(df, 1, sum)
df
   0 1 Total
4  3 8    11
6  4 3     7
8 12 2    14
```

Comment: Why to use `apply(df, 1, sum)` to sum each row instead of `rowSums(df)`? It's inefficient.

Comment: When I post a question to SO I'm always grateful for multiple solutions because I can learn from them even though the answers may differ in efficiency. And a solution that may lag in efficiency in the context of one problem may outshine other solutions in efficiency in other contexts.

Comment: @Darren Tsai Forgot to say a word about your assessment "It's inefficient." How do you measure efficiency? The main criterion, in my mind, is whether code accomplishes what it is supposed to accomplish. That is the case. So surely you must apply some other criterion to assess efficiency. Maybe a good idea to specify that criterion when assessing somebody's solution. Without such specification, the assessment comes across as rude.

Comment: I meant no offense. To focus on how to sum each row of a dataset, `rowSums()` is a "standard" way in R. For example, if you need to sum many numbers, you must use `sum()` instead of writing a for loop. It's why I said "standard". In addition, `apply(df, 1, sum)` is indeed much more time-consuming. It's why I said "inefficient". You can use the following code to test: `m <- 1000 ; n <- 50 ; df <- matrix(rnorm(m*n), m, n) ; library(microbenchmark) ; bm <- microbenchmark(apply = apply(df, 1, sum),rowSums = rowSums(df)) ; bm`

Comment: Fair point. But there's no indication in the OP that they have such a huge dataframe that the difference in split seconds would make itself felt. And even if size does matter, the qualification of `apply(df, 1, sum)` as "inefficient" is unjust and should be replaced by "less efficient"