# How would you go about plotting the this table with multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

[image: Table]

How would you go about making one plot that contains the numbers in each element on the y-axis and the years on the x-axis? Each row (ID) is a set data that should be connected with a line or something similar.

Comment: I would try the `tidyverse` using `gather`. Then `ggplot2`

Comment: @Jimbou: I tried using the ggplot2 but I couldn't quite get it to work. I only have experience plotting with two columns, not multiple like in this case.

Comment: @Woels I have given the hint in my first comment. So google for "transform data from wide to long" . If you need more specific help, provide some data using `dput()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264744/draw-histograms-per-row-over-multiple-columns-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Jimbou: I tried using the gather function, but it also gathers the IDs and when i try to use the ggplot function, it doesn't display anything?

Comment: @WoeIs I repeat my comment above, If you need more specific help, provide some data using `dput()` rather posting pictures of the data.